# Search and replace multiple words in over 500.000 rows based on lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to replace every SKU with a corresponding ID in over 500.000 rows of text data.

I have the following tables:

data_table (500.000 rows) with a single column

ORDERS

```
{"sku":7440793A,"quantity":1,"price":55.9600}
{"sku":6346060A,"quantity":1,"price":127.2000},{"sku":6412518A,"quantity":1,"price":231.2000},{"sku":6309954A,"quantity":1,"price":71.9600}
{"sku":6209832A,"quantity":1,"price":7196.0000}
{"sku":1160576A,"quantity":1,"price":959.2000},{"sku":1120922A,"quantity":2,"price":71.9600}
```

lookup_table (86.000 rows)

SKU | ID

```
7440793A|1234
6346060A|2345
6309954A|3456
1160576A|6789
```

For each line in the data_table I need to iterate through the lookup_table and replace all occurrences.

After quite a bit of googling I tried this simple piece of code:

```
select ORDERS, replace(t1.ORDERS, lt.SKU, lt.ID) as orders_replaced
from   data_table t1 left outer join lookup_table lt on t1.ORDERS like '%' || lt.SKU || '%'
```

But there are several issues:

1. It creates 500.000 x 86.000 rows, no matter how I join the two tables
2. It does not actually replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should use '+' instead of '||':

```
select ORDERS, replace(t1.ORDERS, lt.SKU, lt.ID) as orders_replaced
from   data_table t1 
inner join lookup_table lt on t1.ORDERS like '%{"sku":' + lt.SKU + '%'
```

Also, taking to account that order can have multiple SKUs, the best way to achive it - with custom function. Create a user-defined function, something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplacementSKU(@order nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @check int = 1
    WHILE @check > 0
        BEGIN
            select @order = replace(@order, lt.sku, lt.id)
            from  lookup_table lt 
            WHERE @order like '%{"sku":' + lt.sku + '%'

        SELECT @check = COUNT(lt.sku) from  lookup_table lt 
            WHERE @order like '%{"sku":' + lt.sku + '%'
        END
    RETURN @order
END
```

And then use this function in your select statement:

```
select dt.*, dbo.ReplacementSKU(dt.ORDER)
from   data_table dt
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql the operator `||` is **not** the concatenation operator, it is the [`logical OR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) (unless you have enabled the `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` mode which is not the case because you get incorrect results).
Use the function [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
select ORDERS, 
  coalesce(replace(t1.ORDERS, lt.SKU, lt.ID), t1.ORDERS) as orders_replaced
from   data_table t1 left outer join lookup_table lt 
on t1.ORDERS like concat('%', lt.SKU, '%')
```